# Cannot read the properties from database?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

where was the problem to those code, the review page cannot read the properties and it shows blank page when called name & others but in the java script output it show on console tab. when i called any properties of the product data output should be blank.
please help me out!
i added the screen shot of the error and output on server.
[enter image description[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma24C.png)on here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEvLs.png)

**Review.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; 
import fakeData from '../../fakeData'; 
import {getDatabaseCart} from '../../utilities/databaseManager';
import ReviewItem from '../ReviewItem/ReviewItem';

const Review = () => {
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    
useEffect(()=>{
    //cart
    const savedCart = getDatabaseCart();
    const productKeys = Object.keys(savedCart);

    const cartProducts =  productKeys.map( key => {
        const product = fakeData.find( pd => pd.key === key);
        
        return product;
    });
    setCart(cartProducts);
}, []);

    


return (
    <div>
        <h1>Cart Item : {cart.length}</h1>
        {
                cart.map(pd => <ReviewItem 
                    key={pd.key}
                    product={pd}></ReviewItem>)
            }
    </div>
);
};

export default Review;
```

**ReviewItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const ReviewItem = (props) => { const {name, quantity, price} = props.product;
return (
    <div >
        <h4 >{name}</h4>
        <p>Quantity: {quantity}</p>
        <p><small>$ {price}</small></p>
        
    </div>
);
};
export default ReviewItem;
```

Please help me out to show the details on review tab

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the line :

```js
const product = fakeData.find( pd => pd.key === key);
```

is the problem ,
where "fakeData" is an array and you are trying to access the property "key" from "pd" which does not exist , you should review "fakeData" or the exported array from it's file

Comment: what should i need to change i cannot understand can you explain in details

Comment: fakeData can be actually an array of objects: `[{key: 'abc', door: 'wooden'}, {key: 'bcd', door: 'metallic'}]`